# How can I convert dynamically generated table into DataTable using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

What I've done is created dynamic HTML table. And now I want to convert this table into  `jQuery DataTables`.

Is there any possible ways for that?

Here I've attached my dynamic `HTML table`.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Rows</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtRows"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Columns</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtCols"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="btnDisplay" value="Display" onClick="ShowTable();"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tbl_DynamicTable" border="1" style="display:none">
        </table>
    </body>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

        function ShowTable()
        {
        debugger;
            document.getElementById("tbl_DynamicTable").style.display = "";
            createTable();
        }

        function createTable()
            {
            debugger;
                var rows = document.getElementById("txtRows").value;
                var cols = document.getElementById("txtCols").value;
                var table = document.getElementById("tbl_DynamicTable");
                var str="";

                var randomColor; 
                for(var i=0;i<rows;i++)
                {
                    randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                    str += "<tr id=row" + i +" bgcolor="+randomColor+">";

                    for(var j=0;j<cols;j++)
                    {
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            str += "<th> Header " + j + "</th>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str += "<td> Row " + i + ", Cell "+ j + "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    str += "</tr>";
                }
                table.innerHTML = str;
            }
    </script>

</html>
```

Now how can I convert this table into jQuery's DataTable?

Comment: I don't have any idea that how to do it. Wait let me put my HTML's dynamic table's code here.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Example:**

**outside the function you declare otable.**

```
var oTable;
```

**Inside a function after create a html table:**

```
 if(oTable.length>0)
       oTable.fnDestroy();


    oTable=$("tableid").dataTable({
                    "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
                    "sScrollY":500,
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bSortClasses": false
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding each dynamic row push that into array and it will store details and after that you can send to databse

Comment: Well, you can see my code now. Please let me know if there is a way through that.

Comment: well, Create a Array variable like: var items={ details[] }; next create one function and call that function when you click submit button, in that function using ajax, push items to array. like: items.details.push({item1,item2}) at the end you will have all the elements in the array and send it to database